# Random Forest Classification, claims very high accuracy, but it isn't even close. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to create a classifier for a dataset with roughly 15 million rows. My training data has about 900k rows.

```
def train_model(df):
    
      X = df.iloc[:, 1:12].values
      y = df.iloc[:,0].values
      X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
    
      scaler = StandardScaler()
      scaler.fit(X_train)
      X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
      X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
    
      model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy', random_state = 0)
      model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
      y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
      from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
      result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
      print("Confusion Matrix:")
      print(result)
      result1 = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
      print("Classification Report:",)
      print (result1)
      result2 = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
      print("Accuracy:",result2)
    
      return model
```

I'm trying to create a classifier that chooses from 8 different classes, which have the following strata (# rows in the df):

```
Class1  9456
Class2  277018
Class3  33926
Class4  106815
Class5  336508
Class6  143470
Class7  71240
Class8  2085
```

Which returns the following model, which on the surface, looks good (too good to be true)

```
Confusion Matrix:
[[ 1712    37     0     2     3     2     0     0]
 [    2 51181     1    11   422    37     1     0]
 [    1   103  6027    15   173    15     2     0]
 [    0   186     6 19358   327    29     6     0]
 [    1   233     7    11 62435    40     7     0]
 [    0   173     1    18   391 26133    10     0]
 [    0   135     1    20   270    32 12828     0]
 [    0     2     0     0     6     0     0   381]]
Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

 Class1       1.00      0.97      0.99      1756
 Class2       0.98      0.99      0.99     51655
 Class3       1.00      0.95      0.97      6336
 Class4       1.00      0.97      0.98     19912
 Class5       0.98      1.00      0.99     62734
 Class6       0.99      0.98      0.99     26726
 Class7       1.00      0.97      0.98     13286
 Class8       1.00      0.98      0.99       389

 accuracy                           0.99    182794
 macro avg       0.99      0.98      0.98    182794
 weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99    182794

Accuracy: 0.985015919559723
```

But when I re-run the training data through the model (without the classifiers) and compare them side-by-side, they aren't even close.

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(f"{project_dir}/week1.csv")
df = week_preprocessing(new_df)
X = df.iloc[:, 0:11].values
y_pred = model.predict(X)
df['class_predicted'] = y_pred
```

The top df.groupby is the output of the classifier, the bottom is the actual training data

```
majorGroup  minorGroup  class_predicted  
2018090600  75          Class2         728
                        Class5         39
            146         Class2         598
                        Class5         39
            168         Class2         585
                        Class5         39
            190         Class5         910
                        Class2         39
            256         Class5         484
                        Class2         33
            320         Class5         673
                        Class2         41
            344         Class5         589
                        Class2         41
            402         Class5         806
Name: frameId, dtype: int64

majorGroup  minorGroup  class    
2018090600  75          Class5     767
            146         Class5     637
            168         Class5     624
            190         Class5     949
            256         Class1     517
            320         Class5     714
            344         Class5     630
            402         Class5     845
            492         Class5    1300
Name: frameId, dtype: int64
```

The training data has all elements of the minorGroup labeled the same, but the predict does not.  In some cases the smallest number of labels is correct (vs the max), but in others, neither are correct.

I'm not sure how I can get such a high 'accuracy" and low actual accuracy.  I'm pretty new to this, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by ```re-run the training data through the model (without the classifiers)```?

Comment: I took off the column that had the Y values and ran it through the classifier.predict(X). I only did this because I noticed the other data going through the predict were only predicting 2 of 8 classes. So I thought I would see how it would predict on the same date it was trained on the it was completely wrong

Comment: Accuracy is generally considered a rather meaningless parameter in classification.  Did you do any cross-validation?

Comment: I should also call out that I did not include the major and minor groups in the model. I made that mistake early and it skewed my results.They are just there to tie the predictions back to the training data

Comment: It's possible that your model is overfitting. Check your `oob_score_` and/or do cross-validation.

Comment: What could be a reason for feeding different data in training `X = df.iloc[:, 1:12]` and predicting `X = df.iloc[:, 0:11]` ?

Comment: @pavel Accuracy *is* a meaningful measure for a classification, though in some cases, where it fails, one may wish to augment it with other metrics. As well. where do you see overfitting for a single folder CV with accuracy `0,98` ?